# Problem sending data in hybi-10 WebSockets server

Tags: javascript, python, protocols, websocket

I'm trying to implement the new hybi-10 protocol in a python server and for now I succeeded in the handshake and receiving data from the client (JavaScript) but now I'm having problems with sending the data to the client.

I'm using a bit of a code from [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/blob/master/websocket.py#L215) (`encode_hybi` function) to encode the frames according to this protocol. But unfortunately the client doesn't seem to receive the data, as the on message event never fires.

So the code I have is this:

```
def encode_hybi(self, buf, opcode = 0x01):

    buf = b64encode(buf)

    b1 = 0x80 | (opcode & 0x0f) 
    payload_len = len(buf)
    if payload_len <= 125:
        header = struct.pack('>BB', b1, payload_len)
    elif payload_len > 125 and payload_len < 65536:
        header = struct.pack('>BBH', b1, 126, payload_len)
    elif payload_len >= 65536:
        header = struct.pack('>BBQ', b1, 127, payload_len)

    print repr(header + buf)

    return header + buf

def send(self, data):
    logging.info("Message Sent: %s" % data)

    if (self.protocol == 'hixie-76'):
        self.client.send("\x00%s\xff" % data)
    elif (self.protocol =='hybi-10'):
        msg = self.encode_hybi(data)
        self.client.send(msg)
```

I'm sending a simple `'OK'` through the socket. So after the encode_hybi function I get: 
`'\x81\x04T0s='` which is sent to JavaScript. I have no response from it, nor errors.

I tried to send other data, for example `'OKKK'`. After the encode_hybi function I get: `'\x81\x08T0tLSw=='`. Don't know if it helps, but with this data sent, the JavaScript presents an error:

> Unrecognized frame opcode: 13.

This error appears every time the length of the data sent is bigger than 3 characters.

I really can't understand the problem. Is something wrong in the encoding?

Comment: What is the client? According to the error it looks like it's Chrome. If so, have a look at chrome://net-internals/. Check the checkbox on the right to capture bytes, then go to chrome://net-internals/#events&q=type:SOCKET%20is:active and look for your socket to see the actual received bytes. Is there anything interesting there?

Comment: Yes I'm using chrome. I did that and for the 'OK' string sent I get 6 byte count [(see here)](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/3654/bytesok.png). But if I send a bigger string, like 'OKKKK', the socket doesn't appear under the is:active tag..

Comment: I see the handshake response ends with `\n\r\n\r\n`. Could you try removing the first `\n`, since it should end with `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: Oh my god, that was it! I will explain: in the handshake I was using python built in encode('base64') which appends a \n at the end everytime. I changed to b64encode function from base64 package and now works just fine. Thank you so much, I was going crazy with this and it was a \n all along :P.

Comment: I had the same exact issue in java, wracking my brain why I could receive messages after handshake but never could send anything. opcode 13, the devil. removing one of the final \r\n worked, since I was completing each line with that anyways, including the sec-websocket-accept line. Almost seems like a bug in the protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `\n\r\n\r\n` at the end of the handshake format, but it should be `\r\n\r\n`. Currently the `\n` is part of the key.

Although I don't understand how you were still able to open a connection, it looks like removing the first `\n` solves the problem.